# Multiple matplotlib plots in same figure + in to pdf-Python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I'm plotting some data based on pandas dataframes and series. Following is a part of my code. This code gives an error.

```
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
fig = plt.figure()

dfs = df['col2'].resample('10t', how='count')
dfs.plot()
plt.show()

reg = df.groupby('col1').size()
reg.sort()
reg[-10:].plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()

pp = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf') 
pp.close()
```

I have two questions.

1. How to plot multiple plots in one output?(Here I get multiple outputs for each and every plot)
2. How to write all these plots in to one pdf?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328958/matplotlib-pyplot-save-the-plots-into-a-pdf) as a related question.

Comment: As i know subplot is the answer to my first question? How to use it?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic answer? Because we have no idea what your dataset looks like!

Comment: @Sukrit Kalra : Yes, a generic answer? Explanation is enough?

Comment: Hi! Were you looking for this kind of a plot? See my answer.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer when it will let you, and can you make it clear what error you were getting?

Comment: @tcaswell : Sure, the problem is my program is huge and I can not put everything here!

Comment: I don't want to see the whole program, just the full stacktrace from the error it raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the part of code which gave me the expected result, there may be more elegant ways to do this;

```
def plotGraph(X):
    fig = plt.figure()
    X.plot()
    return fig


plot1 = plotGraph(dfs)
plot2 = plotGraph2(reg[:-10])
pp = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
pp.savefig(plot1)
pp.savefig(plot2)
pp.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [following](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#targeting-different-subplots) for targeting different subplots with Pandas.

I am assuming you need 2 subplots (in row fashion). Thus, your code may be modified as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

dfs = df['col2'].resample('10t', how='count')
dfs.plot(ax=axes[0])

reg = df.groupby('col1').size()
reg.sort()
reg[-10:].plot(kind='barh',ax=axes[0])

plt.savefig('foo.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks Batra! Any way I found a different approach to do this

Comment: You may wish to then add your own answer for the same, so that others might benefit by the same.

Comment: Ok, sure :) I'll provide it!

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib` merges the plots to one figure by default. See the following snippet -

```
>>> import pylab as plt
>>> randomList = [randint(0, 40) for _ in range(10)]
>>> randomListTwo = [randint(0, 40) for _ in range(10)]
>>> testFigure = plt.figure(1)
>>> plt.plot(randomList)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x03F24A90>]
>>> plt.plot(randomListTwo)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x030B9FB0>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Gives you a figure like the following -

[image]

Also, the file can be easily saved in PDF through the commands you posted -

```
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
>>> pp = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
>>> testFigure.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
>>> pp.close()
```

This gave me a PDF with a similar figure.

Comment: Hey,Thanks very much! Anyway by the time I figured out how to do it :)!