# Efficient multipage PDF creation using matplotlib subplots in Python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I am new to Python and trying to visualize a huge amount of data in a single multipage pdf output file using matplotlib subplot figures with the matplotlib PdfPages backend. My problem is that I've found a bottleneck I don't know how to solve. Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

with PdfPages("myfigures.pdf") as pdf:
    for i in range(1000):
        f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)
        plt.subplots(2, 3)
        axarr[0, 0].plot(x1, y1)
        axarr[1, 0].plot(x2, y2)

        pdf.savefig(f)
        plt.close("all")
```

Creating a figure in each iteration of a for loop seems highly time-consuming, but if I put it outside the loop the previous figures do not get cleared when plotting the next. Other options I tried like `clear()` or `clf()` didn't work either, or ended up creating multiple different figures (when what I need is an array of subplots gathered and output as a single figure to pdf). Does anyone have an idea of how to implement this? And perhaps also make it faster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Multipage PDF](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html) appending with `matplotlib`

### Create *-rows × -cols* matrices of subplot `axes` arrays per `pdf` *page* & save (append) as each page's matrix of subplots becomes completely full → then create new page, repeat, .

To contain large numbers of subplots as multipage output inside a single pdf, immediately start filling the first page with your plot(s), then you'll need to create a new page after detecting that the latest subplot addition in your iteration of plot generation has maxed out the available space in the current page's -rows × -cols subplot-array layout [i.e., an  ×  matrix of subplots], as applicable.

#### Here's a way to do it where the dimensions ( × ) controlling the number of subplots per page can easily be changed:

```py
    import sys

    import matplotlib
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np


    matplotlib.rcParams.update({"font.size": 6})

    # Dimensions for any m-rows × n-cols array of subplots / pg.
    m, n = 4, 5

    # Don't forget to indent after the with statement
    with PdfPages("auto_subplotting.pdf") as pdf:

        """Before beginning the iteration through all the data,
        initialize the layout for the plots and create a
        representation of the subplots that can be easily
        iterated over for knowing when to create the next page
        (and also for custom settings like partial axes labels)"""
        f, axarr = plt.subplots(m, n, sharex="col", sharey="row")
        arr_ij = [(x, y) for x, y in np.ndindex(axarr.shape)]
        subplots = [axarr[index] for index in arr_ij]

        # To conserve needed plotting real estate,
        # only label the bottom row and leftmost subplots
        # as determined automatically using m and n
        splot_index = 0
        for s, splot in enumerate(subplots):
            splot.set_ylim(0, 0.15)
            splot.set_xlim(0, 50)
            last_row = m * n - s < n + 1
            first_in_row = s % n == 0
            if last_row:
                splot.set_xlabel("X-axis label")
            if first_in_row:
                splot.set_ylabel("Y-axis label")

        # Iterate through each sample in the data
        for sample in range(33):

            # As a stand-in for real data, let's just make numpy take 100 random draws
            # from a poisson distribution centered around say ~25 and then display
            # the outcome as a histogram
            scaled_y = np.random.randint(20, 30)
            random_data = np.random.poisson(scaled_y, 100)
            subplots[splot_index].hist(
                random_data,
                bins=12,
                normed=True,
                fc=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                lw=0.75,
                ec="b",
            )

            # Keep collecting subplots (into the mpl-created array; 
            # see: [1]) through the samples in the data and increment
            # a counter each time. The page will be full once the count is equal
            # to the product of the user-set dimensions (i.e. m * n)
            splot_index += 1

            """Once an mxn number of subplots have been collected 
            you now have a full page's worth, and it's time to 
            close and save to pdf that page and re-initialize for a
            new page possibly. We can basically repeat the same 
            exact code block used for the first layout 
            initialization, but with the addition of 3 new lines:
             +2 for creating & saving the just-finished pdf page,
             +1 more to reset the subplot index (back to zero)"""
            if splot_index == m * n:
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.close(f)
                f, axarr = plt.subplots(m, n, sharex="col", sharey="row")
                arr_ij = [(x, y) for x, y in np.ndindex(axarr.shape)]
                subplots = [axarr[index] for index in arr_ij]
                splot_index = 0
                for s, splot in enumerate(subplots):
                    splot.set_ylim(0, 0.15)
                    splot.set_xlim(0, 50)
                    last_row = (m * n) - s < n + 1
                    first_in_row = s % n == 0
                    if last_row:
                        splot.set_xlabel("X-axis label")
                    if first_in_row:
                        splot.set_ylabel("Y-axis label")

        # Done!
        # But don't forget to save to pdf after the last page    
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close(f)
```

For any *m×n* layout, just change the declarations for the values of *m* and *n*, respectively. From the code above (where "`m, n = 4, 5`"), a 4x5 matrix of subplots with a total 33 samples is produced as a two-page pdf output file:

[image]

### References

1. [Link to matplotlib subplots official docs.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

> *Note*:
> There will be, on the final page of the multipage PDF, a number of blank subplots equal to the remainder from the the product of your chosen subplots  ×  layout dimension numbers and your total number of samples/data to plot. E.g., say m=3, and n=4, thus you get 3 rows of 4 subplots each equals 12 per page, and if you had say 20 samples, then there would be a two-page pdf auto-created with a total of 24 subplots with the last 4 (so full bottom-most row in this hypothetical example) of subplots on the second page empty.

---

## Using `seaborn`

### For a more advanced (& more "*pythonic*"<sup>*</sup>) extension of the implementation above, see below:

The multipage handling should probably be simplified by creating a `new_page` function; it's better to not repeat code verbatim*, especially if you start customizing the plots in which case you won't want to have to mirror every change and type the same thing twice. A more customized aesthetic based off of `seaborn` and utilizing the available `matplotlib` parameters like shown below might be preferable too.

Add a `new_page` function & some customizations for the subplot style:

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import seaborn as sns

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

    # this erases labels for any blank plots on the last page
    sns.set(font_scale=0.0)
    m, n = 4, 6
    datasize = 37 
    # 37 % (m*n) = 13, (m*n) - 13 = 24 - 13 = 11. Thus 11 blank subplots on final page
    
    # custom colors scheme / palette
    ctheme = [
        "k", "gray", "magenta", "fuchsia", "#be03fd", "#1e488f",
        (0.44313725490196076, 0.44313725490196076, 0.88627450980392153), "#75bbfd",
        "teal", "lime", "g", (0.6666674, 0.6666663, 0.29078014184397138), "y",
        "#f1da7a", "tan", "orange", "maroon", "r", ] # pick whatever colors you wish
    colors = sns.blend_palette(ctheme, datasize)
    fz = 7  # labels fontsize


    def new_page(m, n):
        global splot_index
        splot_index = 0
        fig, axarr = plt.subplots(m, n, sharey="row")
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.15)
        arr_ij = [(x, y) for x, y in np.ndindex(axarr.shape)]
        subplots = [axarr[index] for index in arr_ij]
        for s, splot in enumerate(subplots):
            splot.grid(
                b=True,
                which="major",
                color="gray",
                linestyle="-",
                alpha=0.25,
                zorder=1,
                lw=0.5,
            )
            splot.set_ylim(0, 0.15)
            splot.set_xlim(0, 50)
            last_row = m * n - s < n + 1
            first_in_row = s % n == 0
            if last_row:
                splot.set_xlabel("X-axis label", labelpad=8, fontsize=fz)
            if first_in_row:
                splot.set_ylabel("Y-axis label", labelpad=8, fontsize=fz)
        return (fig, subplots)


    with PdfPages("auto_subplotting_colors.pdf") as pdf:

        fig, subplots = new_page(m, n)

        for sample in xrange(datasize):
            splot = subplots[splot_index]
            splot_index += 1
            scaled_y = np.random.randint(20, 30)
            random_data = np.random.poisson(scaled_y, 100)
            splot.hist(
                random_data,
                bins=12,
                normed=True,
                zorder=2,
                alpha=0.99,
                fc="white",
                lw=0.75,
                ec=colors.pop(),
            )
            splot.set_title("Sample {}".format(sample + 1), fontsize=fz)
            # tick fontsize & spacing
            splot.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=4, labelsize=6)
            splot.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=4, labelsize=6)

            # make new page:
            if splot_index == m * n:
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.close(fig)
                fig, subplots = new_page(m, n)

        if splot_index > 0:
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close(f)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, kinda overkill but thak you very much, it works wonderfull, could I ask if the code comes from some kinda webpage? It is very interesting

Comment: no prob--just wanted to be thorough, I actually use this at work all the time so it was a good refresher for me too. thx I came up with the code for analyzing dna sequencing results that needed sort of atypical custom formats and I wanted presentable figures in a more tailored/less obviously-default matplotlib style.

Comment: This is a really nice solution.