# PdfPages in Matplotlib saves the same figure twice

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code provided [in the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/specialty_plots/hinton_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-hinton-demo-py) creates Hinton diagrams:

```
def hinton(matrix, max_weight=None, ax=None):
    """Draw Hinton diagram for visualizing a weight matrix."""
    ax = ax if ax is not None else plt.gca()

    if not max_weight:
        max_weight = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log(np.abs(matrix).max()) / np.log(2))

    ax.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(pl.NullLocator())
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(pl.NullLocator())

    for (x, y), w in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
        color = 'white' if w > 0 else 'black'
        size = np.sqrt(np.abs(w) / max_weight)
        rect = pl.Rectangle([x - size / 2, y - size / 2], size, size,
                             facecolor=color, edgecolor=color)
        ax.add_patch(rect)

    ax.autoscale_view()
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

I would like to create two Hinton diagrams: one for the weights going from the input to the hidden layer, and one going from the hidden layer to the output layer in my one-layer MLP. I have tried ([based on this jupyter notebook](https://github.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/keras/convmnist/keras_cnn_mnist.ipynb)):

```
W = model_created.layers[0].kernel.get_value(borrow=True)
W = np.squeeze(W)
print("W shape : ", W.shape) # (153, 15)

W_out = model_created.layers[1].kernel.get_value(borrow=True)
W_out = np.squeeze(W_out)
print('W_out shape : ', W_out.shape) # (15, 8)

with PdfPages('hinton_again.pdf') as pdf:
    h1 = hinton(W)
    h2 = hinton(W_out)
    pdf.savefig()
```

I have also tried ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328958/matplotlib-pyplot-save-the-plots-into-a-pdf?rq=1)):

```
h1 = hinton(W)
h2 = hinton(W_out)

pp = PdfPages('hinton_both.pdf')
pp.savefig(h1)
pp.savefig(h2)
pp.close()
```

Regardless, the outcome is the same: the Hinton diagram for W gets plotted twice. How can I include a Hinton diagram for my first set of weights and a Hinton diagram for my second set of weights in the same pdf (I would also settle for two separate pdfs, as long as I can get both Hinton diagrams)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pdf.savefig()` command saves the current figure. As there is only one current figure, it will save it twice. In order to get two figures, they need to be created, e.g. via `plt.figure(1)` and `plt.figure(2)`.

```
with PdfPages('hinton_again.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.figure(1)
    h1 = hinton(W)
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.figure(2)
    h2 = hinton(W_out)
    pdf.savefig()
```

There are of course tons of different ways to save the two plots, anotherone might be

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hinton(W, ax=ax)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
hinton(W_out, ax=ax2)

with PdfPages('hinton_again.pdf') as pdf:
   pdf.savefig(fig)
   pdf.savefig(fig2)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. The only change I added was to use pl.figure(1) and pl.figure(2), as I imported pylot as pl, not plt