# Want to save multiple plots in PDF document

Tags: python

I want to save every plot in a PDF document, but only the last plot is saved.

Here is my code:

```
for pair in indices:
    y1 = c[pair[0]]
    y2 = c[pair[1]]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.plot(x, y1, "-o", color='b')
    plt.ylabel(pair[0])

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x, y2,"-o" ,color='r')
    for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
        tl.set_color('r')

    plt.title('Reihe')
    plt.ylabel(pair[1])

    plt.savefig("title2.pdf", dpi=300)
```

Comment: Please do not post images on stack-overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib.pyplot : Save the plots into a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328958/matplotlib-pyplot-save-the-plots-into-a-pdf)

Comment: @U8-Forward Posting images in general is no problem, but *code* should be posted as text, not as an image.

Comment: Do you want a separate PDF file for each plot, or a single PDF file that contains all plots?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my Problem is, last plot is only saved because of the Loop. All plots are displayed, but not saved in PDF.

Comment: I want a single Pdf File.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python saving multiple figures into one PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788685/python-saving-multiple-figures-into-one-pdf-file)

Comment: Sorry, doesn' t work, error Code <Figure object is not callable>