# Export python file to PDF without code i.e only with outputs

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, latex, pdflatex

I have been trying to find a way to convert my python file to pdf.
I found latex, pyweave and others but I am unable to understand on how not to include input code in my pdf. Also, how to use pyweave?
My pdf should not contain any code, just the ouputs.
How do i achieve it?

In jupyter we've nbconvert tool with --no input flag. 
How about in regular python file?

Answer (score 0):

The python package might be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
print("42")
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

(needs to be compiled with shell-escape enabled)

Comment: Which package is this?

Comment: @rojoka The package is called `python`

Answer (score 0):

**One of the ways possible:** https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/saving-the-python-output-as-textfile/14987/2 referring to the above post

**1.** Create an empty python string

```
output_string = ''
```

**2.** Start adding all the possible outcomes into output_string

```
# If you want perform print(some_object), add it to the string
output_string = output_string + str(some_object) + "\n"
```

**3.** Convert string into a pdf file using any technique

Comment: I have pandas plots and dfs too

Comment: It works for dfs, I tried. For plots you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328958/save-the-plots-into-a-pdf