# Create separate graph of each series and save as pdf in Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

|  | Well Name | READTIME | WL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 02-Jul-20 | 12 |
| 1 | B | 03-Aug-22 | 18 |
| 2 | C | 05-Jul-21 | 14 |
| 3 | A | 03-May-21 | 16 |
| 4 | B | 01-Jan-19 | 19 |
| 5 | C | 12-Dec-20 | 20 |
| 6 | D | 14-Nov-21 | 14 |
| 7 | A | 01-Mar-22 | 17 |
| 8 | B | 15-Feb-21 | 11 |
| 9 | C | 10-Oct-20 | 10 |
| 10 | D | 14-Sep-21 | 5 |

```
groupByName = df.groupby(['Well Name', 'READTIME'])
```

After grouping them by 'Well Name' and Readtime, i got the following:

```
Well Name   READTIME    WL  
A           2020-07-02  12
            2021-05-03  16
            2022-03-01  17
B           2019-01-01  19
            2021-02-15  11
            2022-08-03  18
C           2020-10-10  10
            2020-12-12  20
            2021-07-05  14
D           2021-09-14  5
            2021-11-14  14
```

I have got the following graph by running this code:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x="READTIME", y="WL", hue="Well Name",kind="line", height=4, aspect=3)
```

[image]

I want to have a separate graph for each "Well Name" and saved it as a pdf. I will really appreciate your help with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To separate out the plots, you can iterate over the four unique Well Names in your dataset and filter the dataset for each Well Name before plotting:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# I saved your data as an Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
print(df)

# Get the set of unique Well Names
well_names = set(df['Well Name'].to_list())
for wn in well_names:
    # Create dataframe containing only rows with this Well Name
    this_wn = df[df['Well Name'] == wn]
    # Plot, save, and show
    sns.relplot(data=this_wn, x="READTIME", y="WL", hue="Well Name",kind="line", height=4, aspect=3)
    plt.savefig(f'{wn}.png')
    plt.show(block=True)
```

This generated the following 4 image files:

[image: A.png]
[image: B]
[image: C]
[image: D]

For saving in a PDF file, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328958/save-multiple-plots-in-a-single-pdf-file).

Comment: Thank you. Its just i had to use this "well_names = set(df['Well Name'].values.tolist())" as I was getting this error if I used .to_list() method, "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'"

Comment: Is it possible that you're not on the latest version of pandas? `to_list()` works in 1.4.3: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case, specifying a row results in a faceted graph.

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x="READTIME", y="WL", hue="Well Name", kind="line", row='Well Name', height=4, aspect=3)
```

[image]