# Can't obtain histogram from pandas grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, pandas-groupby, frequency-distribution

I have this DF.

```
f = { 'Router_name':['count'] }
a = a.groupby(['Week_end']).agg(f)
```

Which produces the following data ..

```
         Router_name
               count
Week_end            
29                 3
30                10
31                 6
32                 4
33                 9
34                 2
35                 5
36                10
37                 8
38                 6
40                10
41                 2
42                 8
43                 1
44                 3
45                 2
46                 8
47                 6
49                12
50                 5
51                10
52                 5
53                11
```

I'm trying to obtain an histogram/frequencies out of the previous aggregated data for `Router_name`. So, for example, the expected output should these frequencies:

[image]

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584029/plotting-histograms-from-grouped-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe) that doing `b = a.hist(by=a['Router_name'])` would do the trick. However, when trying that I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_report_v1.5_devel.py", line 465, in <module>
    b = a.hist(by=a['Router_name'])
    raise ValueError("Grouper for '%s' not 1-dimensional" % t)
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

I also tried this: `a.Router_name.hist()`. But I get the same DataFrame.

How can I obtain the frequencies for a given column out of a grouped data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seems like you create the multi index by using the `agg`

```
a.hist(by=a[('Router_name','count')])

a[('Router_name','count')].value_counts()
Out[1678]: 
10    4
8     3
6     3
5     3
2     3
3     2
12    1
11    1
9     1
4     1
1     1
Name: (Router_name, sum), dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi! Tried your suggestion but, when trying to print the resulting table, I get something like a series of lists: `[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f1e87b67588> <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f1e87be2da0>]`.  Further, I tried plotting it (`ax1 = b.plot(.)`) and got: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'`. How do I manage this result?

Comment: @LucasAimaretto the result is according to the link you shared, can you show your expected output?

Comment: Hi @Wen, I've updated the question to show what I'm expecting to get. It's basically obtaining the frequencies of occurrences of the grouped data. In Excel/Calc you can do that with a PivotTable or by using the `Frequency()` formula.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto that is value_counts

Comment: Nice! The only thing is that the resulting table's first column is not sorted. If you see my example, the first column goes from 1 to 12, ascending. The result of *my* `value_counts()` gives me a first column with this sequence: 1,4,9,11,12,3,2,5,6,8,10. Can I sort that somehow?

Comment: @LucasAimaretto adding sort=False  `a[('Router_name','sum')].value_counts(sort=False)`

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: @LucasAimaretto yw~ Happy coding