# Making grouped histograms bigger in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram

I am drawing some grouped histograms in python as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584029/plotting-histograms-from-grouped-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but am trying to plot more histograms and make them bigger.

To give an example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
x = ['A']*300 + ['B']*400 + ['C']*300 + ['D']*400 + ['E']*200 + ['F']*500 + 
['G']*400 + ['H']*500 + ['I']*300
y = np.random.randn(3300)
df = DataFrame({'Letter':x, 'N':y})
grouped = df.groupby('Letter')
```

I then plot like this in Jupyter:

```
%matplotlib inline
df['N'].hist(by=df['Letter'])
```

but the plots come out really small. How do I increase the size so they fill the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wasn't that difficult:

```
df['N'].hist(by=df['Letter'], figsize = (16,18))
```

Comment: note: the values after figsize must be in parenthesis and mean `(width, heigth)`. Another method would be before `df['N'].hist()` a line with `plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))` if you had previously imported `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, that is.