# Make 3 histograms in the same figure by ordering x-axis values

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, matplotlib, histogram, bin

l would like to plot histograms of three vectors sharing the same x-axis which is classes. Classes (101 string values) is a set of labels

```
classes={'playingguitar', 'billiards', 'boxingboxingspeedbag', 'applylipstick', 'playingsitar', 'fieldhockeypenalty', 'blowingcandles', 'longjump', 'playingdhol', 'biking', 'playingpiano', 'handstandwalking', 'playingcello', 'ropeclimbing', 'hulahoop', 'cricketshot', 'punch', 'pushups', 'floorgymnastics', 'jumpingjack', 'lunges', 'golfswing', 'bandmarching', 'skiing', 'playingtabla', 'archery', 'breaststroke', 'unevenbars', 'playingviolin', 'babycrawling', 'moppingfloor', 'bowling', 'knitting', 'rockclimbingindoor', 'shavingbeard', 'writingonboard', 'shotput', 'stillrings', 'drumming', 'applyeyemakeup', 'cuttinginkitchen', 'pizzatossing', 'soccerpenalty', 'bodyweightsquats', 'taichi', 'benchpress', 'trampolinejumping', 'playingdaf', 'pullups', 'pommelhorse', 'jumprope', 'headmassage', 'horserace', 'skijet', 'surfing', 'basketballdunk', 'polevault', 'brushingteeth', 'salsaspin', 'frontcrawl', 'horseriding', 'typing', 'throwdiscus', 'nunchucks', 'diving', 'balancebeam', 'highjump', 'volleyballspiking', 'icedancing', 'cricketbowling', 'rafting', 'yoyo', 'walkingwithdog', 'swing', 'hammering', 'mixing', 'wallpushups', 'parallelbars', 'skateboarding', 'skydiving', 'jugglingballs', 'soccerjuggling', 'kayaking', 'cleanandjerk', 'tennisswing', 'playingflute', 'javelinthrow', 'haircut', 'blowdryhair', 'cliffdiving', 'frisbeecatch', 'boxingspeedbag', 'handstandpushups', 'militaryparade', 'hammerthrow', 'rowing', 'basketball', 'baseballpitch', 'tabletennisshot', 'fencing', 'sumowrestling'}
len(classes)=101
```

In `labels2`, `labels2_test`, `labels2_full_train` we have the number of occurence of each class in different order :

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
labels2, values2 = zip(*Counter(train2).items())
labels2_test, values_test2 = zip(*Counter(test).items())
labels2_full_train, values2_full_train = zip(*Counter(full_train).items())
```

l would like to make a plot such that x-axis represents classes and y-axis number of occurrence of each class in `values2, values_test2, values2_full_train`

**What l have tried ?**

```
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (30, 10)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.tick_params(rotation=90)
ax1.plot(labels2, values2, label='train classes')
ax1.plot(labels2_test, values_test2, label='test classes')
ax1.plot(labels2_full_train,  values2_full_train, label='test classes')
ax1.set_xlabel("classes",rotation='vertical')
ax1.set_ylabel("number of examples")
ax1.set_title("data distibution")
ax1.legend(loc='best')
fig1.show()
```

However l get something as follow : [image]

since `labels2`, `labels2_test`, `labels2_full_train` are not ordered in the same way in

```
labels2, values2 = zip(*Counter(train2).items())
labels2_test, values_test2 = zip(*Counter(test).items())
labels2_full_train, values2_full_train = zip(*Counter(full_train).items())
```

So how can l get `labels2`, `labels2_test`, `labels2_full_train` in the same order (for instance as defined in classes) ?

For instance

```
labels2=['rafting', 'punch', 'applyeyemakeup',...]
values2=[78, 112, 106,...]
labels2_test=['typing', 'surfing', 'cricketbowling',..]
values_test2=[46, 38, 39,...]
labels2_full_train=['archery', 'benchpress', 'brushingteeth',...]
values2_full_train=[1046, 1043, 1065,...]
```

thank you

Comment: As commented below your last question: The order of the labels is always the same. It is alphabetical. If you want to have a line through the points which follows this order, you need to sort the input data by the string values previous to plotting.

Comment: Do you need help with sorting one list on the items of another one? In how far did other questions on sorting lists here on SO not help you?

Comment: l tried  for example labels2, values2 = sorted(zip(*Counter(train2).items())) but it's not accepted . TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes l need help to sort one list on the items of another one

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, l just checked , the string are not ordered alphabetically. For instance  archery class is supposed to be at the beginning however l find it in the middle of the list for labels2 and in the last for labels2_test.

Comment: What I meant to say is "The order of the **tick**labels **in the plot** is always the same. It is alphabetical.", sorry I did not think about you calling your lists "label" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

Because matplotlib shows categorical variables sorted on the axes, you need to sort the lists alphabetically before plotting. So let's create a complete and verifiable example:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = list("ABADEAABEDDAEDBBBBBD") # letters A, B, D, E
list2 = list("AABAEEDCCFFFEDABEEC")  # all letters A-F

items1, counts1 = zip(*sorted(Counter(list1).items()))
items2, counts2 = zip(*sorted(Counter(list2).items()))


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(items1, counts1, label="list1")
plt.plot(items2, counts2, label="list2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note that the first list contains a subset of the all possible items. The output looks like this:

[image]

So unfortunately, although the lists themselves are sorted, the plot shows some strange behaviour in that the axes shows `C` and `F` at the end.

#### The solution

The solution to this would be to let the axis know about **all** possible items to plot beforehands. We could e.g. plot an invisible plot of all items to the axes,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(items1+items2, [5]*len(items1+items2), visible=False)

plt.plot(items1, counts1, "o-", label="list1")
plt.plot(items2, counts2, "o-", label="list2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. sorry for this question l didn't mention it. l would to get histograms for that data and not a plot as did it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib but the problem of bins persists

Comment: You mean replace `plot` with `bar`?

Comment: in you example it will  be a  bins of A B C D E F  for list1 and bins of A B C D E F  for list2