# how to concatenate two histograms in python

Tags: python-3.x, histogram

[The highlighted part is the one I am having problem with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOwF3.jpg) I have imported numpy in python to make two histograms of image pixels. But cannot clearly figure out how to concatenate both the histograms together into one histogram?

Comment: please put on your code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot two histograms at the same time with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib)

Comment: I have attached the snippet of my code. And more importantly I do not want to plot the two histograms. I just want to concatenate the values

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by concatenate. I'm assuming you want multiple histograms side-by-side. If this is the case, your questions has already been answered here: [Plot two histograms at the same time with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib)

Comment: thank you so much. but that is not my question actually. I want to concatenate the values that are stored in the excel sheet.