# Plot Large amounts of data in multiple histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram for my data which looks something like this :

```
id  date   purchase  visit

id1 date1    $10      0 

id1 date1    $50      0

id1 date2    $30      1

id2 date1    $10      0

id2 date2    $10      1

id2 date3  $10        2
```

Basically each row is one transaction for a  customer in a day. 
Visit column keeps track of previous visits per day in a cumulative fashion. Each time same customer visits on new day it increases by 1.

How can I create a histogram that shows the distinct visits per customer. A distinct visit is defined as a customer visiting the store on two separate days.

Total unique customers = 1215 
Total rows = 1135067

I tried to run the following :

```
import random
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

bins = df['visit'].unique() 
uniq_id = df['id'].unique()

pyplot.hist(df['date'], bins, alpha=0.5, label=df['id']) 

pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

Taken intution from plotting multiple histograms here : [Plot two histograms at the same time with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib)

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Do you get an error or does your plot not look right?

Comment: The process never gave an output. It just kept on running for a couple of hours ..

Comment: What is the length of bins? Try removing your label to see if that helps with speed. I can't produce your error without an example tor un.