# Down sample a numpy vector before plotting in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two variables which are represented by a `Numpy` array of size `1000000x1`. I would like to use `matplotlib` to plot both of them in the same plot. However, If I proceed and plot them together the result is unintelligible since I have so many values I cannot really understand a lot. Is there a way that I can downsample and plot a more sparse representation of both variables?

```
plt.plot(acc1) #acc1 contains 10000000 samples
plt.plot(acc2) #acc2 contains 10000000 samples
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not quite sure If I really understand your question... can you give a example for that? And or... just plot `acc1 - acc2` if you want to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take every x sample as follows

```
downsample = 100 # 100x times (or every 100th sample)
plt.plot(acc1[::downsample]) #acc1 contains 10000000/downsample samples
plt.plot(acc2[::downsample]) #acc2 contains 10000000/downsample samples
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try binning your series using `numpy.linspace` and `plt.hist` working example below. Related stackoverflow post: [Plot two histograms at the same time with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib)

```
import random
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

acc1 = [random.gauss(3,1) for _ in range(10000000)]
acc2 = [random.gauss(4,2) for _ in range(10000000)]

bins = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

pyplot.hist(acc1, bins, alpha=0.5, label='x')
pyplot.hist(acc2, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I think in such way with hist i do not plot what I want though.

Comment: So then you need to think about if you want to alter your data (sampling) or if you want to change up your plot. Are you plotting a scatter, two lines or something else?

Comment: I can alter my data and keep sub-samples of them.

Comment: Then you need to find a sampling strategy. Seems a little out of scope for the question you asked. If you are okay with taking, say every nth element you can do a slice on your array. Example: `sub_acc1 = acc1[0::10]` start at 0 and take every 10th element. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing