# How do I graph a distribution curve that shows percent of total population on the Y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to graph the distribution of salary grouped by region, with the y-axis showing the % of people having that salary.

So far I have been able to come up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
records = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John','Rachel','Tom','Stan','Jack','Ben','Joe','Juliet','Nigel','Veronica','Cam'], 
         'salary': [40104,29401,57383,38494,99302,44733,40242,49555,13934,44011,88920],
                     'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'China', 'China', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'France'],
                     'Region': ['America', 'America', 'America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia','Europe']})
```

```
recordsgraph = records.pivot(columns='Region',values='salary')
recordsgraph.plot.density()
```

[image]

But I want the y-axis to show the percentage of the population for each region that has that salary. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: `records['salary'].hist(by=records['Region'], density=True)`?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [density plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.density.html) draws a [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (kde) approximating the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). Such a function is scaled such that the total area equals `1`. The y-axis will show the estimated probability of one unit on the x-axis. So, in this case, a value of `2.5e-5` means there is a `0.0025 %` chance that the salary is exactly some given x-value plus or minus a half. E.g. that it is between `44,220` and `44,221`.

You'll probably want a more coarse range. Let's say you'd want a range of `5000`. If you multiply the values on the y-axis with 5000 (and with 100), you'll get the percentual probability that a salary will be in the range of a given x-value plus or minus 2500. The code below shows a way to multiply the y-values without touching the data, using a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import pandas as pd

def percentage_base_5000(x, pos):
    return f'{x * 5000 * 100:.1f} %'

records = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['John', 'Rachel', 'Tom', 'Stan', 'Jack', 'Ben', 'Joe', 'Juliet', 'Nigel', 'Veronica', 'Cam'],
     'salary': [40104, 29401, 57383, 38494, 99302, 44733, 40242, 49555, 13934, 44011, 88920],
     'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'China', 'China', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'France'],
     'Region': ['America', 'America', 'America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Europe']})
recordsgraph = records.pivot(columns='Region', values='salary')
ax = recordsgraph.plot.density()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(percentage_base_5000))
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage for a 5000-range salary')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that a side-effect of a `FuncFormatter` is that the values shown in the status bar will get the same transformation. So, the cursor value of `x=3.67e4 y=11.7 %` means that a salary between 36700-2500 and 36700+2500 has an estimated probabilty of about 11.7 %.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to change the y-axis to show the percentage, then this can be easily solved by applying a `Formatter` from `matplotlib` to the yaxis tick labels. Specifically, you can try the following:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

recordsgraph = records.pivot(columns='Region', values='salary')
ax = recordsgraph.plot.density()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=1)) # xmax means the percent is calculated out of a max value of 0
```

Now, since this is a kernel density plot, you might find that the % points are very very low. For example:

[image]

If you need some more descriptive values (e.g. 10% of salaries fall into this bin), you might want to consider using a histogram instead. With the amount of data you have shown us there is little data to construct bins, but if you have more data you can it like this:

```py
plt.hist([recordsgraph[col] for col in recordsgraph.columns], 
         bins=30,
         label=[col for col in recordsgraph.columns])
```

(per the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-on-single-chart-with-matplotlib))