# How to make R side by side two column histogram (see images)

Tags: r, plot, histogram

[image: This is what I want]How to make R side by side two column histogram (above) which I am able to do in python ([image taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-on-single-chart-with-matplotlib)) and all the answers I have found for R get [image: this result][image taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r)

I tried searching for answers on stackoverflow and just google in general but no one seemed to be able to tell me how to make the histogram I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `position = 'dodge'` in the `geom_bar` command plot bars side by side. You can use something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

variable_x <- c(5,47,31,9,37,10,35,28,16,29,14,34)
variable_y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
variable_z <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

df <- data.frame(variable_x, variable_y, variable_z)
df <- melt(df, id.vars='variable_z')

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=variable_z, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set.
First you have to bring the data in long format with `pivot_longer`

and then apply `geom_histogram()` with `position= 'dodge'`

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill=name))+
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

[image]